# How to convert a list with dictionaries into new pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe which has a list of dictionaries as a column: This column has the following format:

```
[{'route_id': '1', 'stop_id': '1'}, {'route_id': '2', 'stop_id': '2'}]
```

How can I convert this column into 4 new columns? I mean: route_id (x2), stop_id(x2) as new columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want 4 new columns or 2? Can you please post a sample of input dataframe with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.explode`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=df.explode&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [275]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[{'route_id': '1', 'stop_id': '1'}, {'route_id': '2', 'stop_id': '2'}]]})

In [276]: df
Out[276]: 
                                                   A
0  [{'route_id': '1', 'stop_id': '1'}, {'route_id...

In [284]: df['A'].explode().apply(pd.Series)
Out[284]: 
  route_id stop_id
0        1       1
0        2       2
```

Comment: Thank you! @Mayank